Simple BPTT for RNN implementation equation question
I am trying to implement simple RNN from scratch to understand the calculations step behind each implementation. Forward Propagation seems straightforward, but backward propagation seems very difficult. Especially the dimension does not match…
def rnn_forward(self, e) :
        for t in range(self.T_x - 1) :
            # single (n_x, n_m) m is training set size in time
            xt = self.cache['X'][:, :, t]
            # hidden state of previous step
            a_prev = self.cache['A'][:, :, t]
            # hidden state of next step is caculated by following weights and biases.
            a_next = tanh(np.dot(self.parameters['W_aa'], a_prev) + np.dot(self.parameters['W_ax'], xt) + self.parameters['b_a'])
            # using softmax as final activation
            yt_pred = softmax(np.dot(self.parameters['W_ya'], a_next) + self.parameters['b_y'])
            self.cache['A'][:, :, (t + 1)] = a_next
            self.cache['Y_pred'][:, :, t] = yt_pred

def rnn_backward(self, e):
        # cost function derivative
        self.cache['dY_pred'] = - (self.cache['Y'] / self.cache['Y_pred'])
        # initialized da
        da_next = np.zeros((self.n_a, self.m))
        for t in reversed(range(self.T_x - 1)) :
            # dimension seems to be (n_y, n_m)
            print(self.cache['dY_pred'][:, :, t].shape)
            # dimension seems to be (n_y, n_m) as well
            print(softmax_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_ya'], self.cache['A'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_y']).shape)
            # following computation would have issues? da_prev is expected to have dim (n_a, n_m), but the dot of (n_y, n_m) and (n_y, n_m) don't give me (n_a, n_m)
            da_prev = np.dot(self.cache['dY_pred'][:, :, t], np.dot(self.parameters['W_ya'].T, softmax_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_ya'], self.cache['A'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_y']))) + da_next
            self.cache['dW_ya'] += np.dot(self.cache['dY_pred'][:, :, t], np.dot(softmax_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_ya'], self.cache['A'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_y']), self.cache['A'][:, :, t].T))
            self.cache['db_y'] += np.dot(self.cache['dY_pred'][:, :, t], softmax_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['Wya'], self.cache['A'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_y']))
            self.cache['dW_aa'] += np.dot(da_prev, np.dot(tanh_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_aa'], self.cache['A'][:, :, (t - 1)]) + np.dot(self.parameters['W_ax'], self.cache['X'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_a']), self.cache['A'][:, :, (t - 1)].T))
            self.cache['dW_ax'] += np.dot(da_prev, np.dot(tanh_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_aa'], self.cache['A'][:, :, (t - 1)]) + np.dot(self.parameters['W_ax'], self.cache['X'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_a']), self.cache['X'][:, :, t].T))
            self.cache['db_a'] += np.dot(da_prev, tanh_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_aa'], self.cache['A'][:, :, (t - 1)]) + np.dot(self.parameters['W_ax'], self.cache['X'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_a']))
            da_next = np.dot(da_prev, np.dot(self.parameters['W_aa'].T, tanh_backward(np.dot(self.parameters['W_aa'], self.cache['A'][:, :, (t - 1)]) + np.dot(self.parameters['W_ax'], self.cache['X'][:, :, t]) + self.parameters['b_a'])))

as the comment in the code, I can’t seem to implement the backprop correctly. The dimension doesn’t go together for da_prev to result in (n_a, n_m) correctly… Did I miss out on something?
Thank you!

notes

may be shouldn't be dot product, should be * or np.multi
should try removing dY_pred first to see dimension and add later

